# Which folder to add a public accessible file in yii-framework?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii-components

I need to upload a public accessible file in yii installation which I can access from url. This is domain verification file. I've uploaded it in /frontend/web folder but it's not accessible directly via url mydomain.com/file.txt

As pointed out below, .htaccess file may be preventing this file to be accessible. Can anyone let me know how to write rule in .htaccess file to allow it?

Comment: It depends on the configuration of your web server. By default the advanced app is expecting that the frontend domain is pointed to `/frontend/web` folder and you should place the domain verification file there. The backend domain is expected to be pointed to the `/backend/web` folder. In yii basic app template it should be in `/web` folder. The inaccessibility of file might be also caused by configuration in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Yes you may be right that .htaccess is preventing it. Do you know how can I allow it by adding a rule in .htaccess file?

Comment: @GeorgeT That depends on what you have in your current `.htaccess` - standard configuration should not block such files.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<Files *.*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
 
<Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.jpeg|.*\.ttf">
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you get the following error.

> You don't have permission to access /frontend/web/ on this server.

Then, add the following rule in your `.htaccess`

```
<Directory "/path/to/frontend/web/">
   Options +Indexes
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here the documentation about [Apache .htaccess permissions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DirectoryListings)